# remove duplicates some value from 2 lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate values from the two list. The expected input and output are shown below:

```
firstList = [['i-am1', 'apple'], ['i-am2', 'orange']]

secondList = [['i-am1', 'apple', 'asks'], ['i-am2', 'orange', 'last one'], ['i-am3', 'banana', 'test ok']]

result = [['i-am3', 'banana', 'test ok']]
```

I tried using set() and it doesn't not work.

```
sumfirstList = set(map(tuple, firstList))
sumsecondList = set(map(tuple, secondList))
result_all = set(sumfirstList) ^ set(sumsecondList)
```

Comment: `firstList` and `secondList` do not have any duplicate elements, the logic by which you arrive at `result` is therefore opaque. Is your question how to only keep items of sublists which don't appear in any sublist of the other list?

Comment: i do not  know what exactly you are trying to do. Your elements are lists and the list are not similar , so there is no duplicate. get us the real data. may an the real question.

Comment: @timgeb python can dedup some element?

Comment: @dopa what....?

Comment: please show what you have done

Comment: just match some value in list and remove ['i-am1', 'apple'], ['i-am2', 'orange']
in secondList.

Comment: @dopa,  try  the answer ..

Answer (score -1):

You could filter based on slice

```
l = list(filter(lambda x: x[:2] not in firstList, secondList))
# [['i-am3', 'banana', 'test ok']]
```